# Can I change my Facebook apps hosting server after my app has already been live?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to change where my Facebook app is hosted. The URL will be the same but IP address will be changed, so I wont need to change the Canvas URL. After some tests it seems this breaks the Facebook app. I now get no callback function from FB requests such as FB.getLoginStatus

Has anyone changed this before?

The code below shows my `FB.getloginstatus()` call which was executing the callback on the old server but now on new one, the callback has stopped working.

```
FB.init({ 
  appId : 'XXXXXXXXXX',
  status : true,
  cookie : true,
  oauth : true, 
  xfbml : true 
}); 

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) { 
  alert("login callback"); 
})
```

Comment: This is not a programming question. Please ask on Facebook directly.

Comment: where on Facebook do I ask them?

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors in your console?

Comment: No, no JavaScript errors

Comment: @Lix in fact there is one error which is - Unsafe JavaScript Attempt to access frame With URL (My canvas URL) from frame with URL (Facebook plugin URL)

Comment: Btw, did you add your channel file?

Comment: @phwd Yes I do have my channel.html

Comment: You do not by any chance have your old server’s IP address set in the `Server-Whitelist` app settings field on the `advanced` settings tab …?

Comment: @CBroe I don't have any IP addresses in the whitelist. I don't think you have to have anything in there. I have tried adding the IP of my server and the IP of the machine I update the app from, but still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Users access your application from you app namespace - `https://apps.facebook.com/app_namespace`

Where you store/host your application is up to you and you can change it whenever you want.  The users will still reach your application via that url.

---

If you are experiencing problems, make sure that your new hosting service supports SSL because Facebook applications are required to be hosted from a secure location.

Comment: But it seems not to work any more after the server change. I understand that I shouldn't have to change anything right? Yet it seems to have stopped me getting callbacks?

Comment: Please update your post with details of exactly what isn't working... Saying "its not working" doesn't give us much to go on :)  Are there any errors being displayed?

Comment: sorry no the app works fine it is only the FB. interactions that no longer seem to be triggering a callback function. See below:

'code'
FB.init({
     appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXX', 
     status     : true,
     cookie     : true,
     oauth      : true,
     xfbml      : true
   });
   
   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
   {
alert("login callback");
})

Comment: I now no longer get the alert in the login callback function which I was before.

Comment: Please update your post with this new info - it'll help us assist you.  [Click the edit link](http://i.imgur.com/oJ9Ok.png).